# Sort registers array without default methods

Tags: python, arrays, list, sorting, object

I want to make a method to sort an array with registers in it by a key.

I have this:

```
class Test:
    pass

def init():
    test = Test()
    test.number= int(input('Enter a number'))
    test.genre = int(input('Enter a number'))
    test.quantity = int(input('Enter a number'))
    return test

def show(ar):
    for i in range(len(ar)):
        print('Number', ar[i].number)

def array_sorted():
    v = [None]*10
    for i in range(0, 10):
        v[i] = init()
        if i != 0:
            if v[i].number < v[i-1].number:
                v[i-1], v[i] = v[i], v[i-1]
    return v

array = array_sorted()
show(array)
```

OUT:

```
Number 2798
Number 4036
Number 4164
Number 6613
Number 9176
Number 1891
Number 9395
Number 252
Number 6255
Number 9505
```

In the "OUT" I generate the objects with "random.randint" method as an example, but as you can see the numbers are not sorted. I want to create an array with Test() objects as elements. But every time I charge a new register in it, the array sorts by the field "number". I can't use any default method like "sort()" method.

Comment: Please fix the code formatting in your post

Comment: Please show example input and what you are getting as output.

Comment: By "default method" do you mean builtins? Do you need to implement your own sort function?

Comment: The code you've shown us is not the code you're running. Note that `init()` doesn't return anything.

Comment: Looks like OP is trying to implement bubble sort from scratch

Comment: @JohnLaRooy La Rooy exactly, how can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This loop only ever lets a new entry be swapped with the one immediately before

```
for i in range(0, 10):
    v[i] = init()
    if i != 0:
        if v[i].number < v[i-1].number:
            v[i-1], v[i] = v[i], v[i-1]
```

You'll need to compare each `v[i]` to each of `v[0]` - `v[i-1]` to find out where it fits.

This means you'll need another loop nested inside

Answer (score 0):

```
# sort the list in place
li.sort(key=lambda x: x.genre)
# return a new list
newLi = sorted(li, key=lambda x: x.genre)
```